# Problems with Cortana and signing in with a a MS account after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade, cortana

After an apparent long but apparently trouble free   upgrade,  my programs  work except that I can not get Cortana installed  and when I try  signing in as a new user  I am also unable to do so (screen turns gray and then closes).
I have tried reinstalling windows 10 upgrade but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 was a major update and as far as I could see 8 times out of 10 it really did not work properly after upgrading... What did the trick for me, and I know you probably don't want to hear that as it is a major pain in the neck, is to reinstall your whole system from scratch... first windows 7 and before installing any software with a fresh install of win7 upgrade to 10... so that the system doesn't have the time to install 3rd party drivers and software that would conflict with the new OS.

Right now, after I spent 2 days reinstalling EVERYTHING, my win10 works fine.. yes it has a LOT of stuff that needs to be polished... and cortana is surprisingly slow.. nothing like Google Now... but it works. It reminds me of the first months of win7...

Comment: Thank you Tony, as you well said ; that is not want I wanted to hear